Lower-bound on a root of a polynomial $px^a - x^b + (1 - p)$
I have a polynomial $px^a - x^b + (1 - p)$, where $a > b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{b}{a} < p < 1$ to make this polynomial has two roots on (0; 1]: $x = 1$ and another root. I want to find a lower bound on a second root. I want it to go to 1 as $p \rightarrow \frac{b}{a}$.
Since the sum of coefficients is zero, $x = 1$ is a root. The roots of a derivative are $x = 0$ and $x = (\frac{b}{ap})^{\frac{1}{a-b}} =: x^*$.
Since:

at $x = 0$ value of a polynomial is greater than zero
for $0 < x < x^*$ the value of a polynomial is decreasing and for $x^* < x < 1$ is increasing
at $x = 1$ there is a root,
there is a one root at $x \in (0; 1)$. I want to find a good lower-bound on it. By good I mean such that it would go to 1 as $p$ goes to $\frac{b}{a}$.

Do you have any ideas?
I was thinking considering $x = \frac{b}{ap}$, but it is quite hard to come up with some good inequalities...
The reformulation of the problem might be: find a lower bound for $x$ with same properties such that: $\frac{1 - x^b}{1 - x^a} > p$. Because:
$$
px^a - x^b + (1 - p) = 1 - x^b - p(1 - x^a)
$$
